# Granting a group of people access to a private repository

Tags: github

Is it possible to grant everyone in a group of people (for example, everyone in a Github organization or everyone in a team within that organization) access to a private repository that is on a private Github Free account? It looks like you can only grant access to individuals or transfer the repository to the organization.